# WearOS cannot make Volley request to an endpoint running on my computer's localhost

Tags: java, android, android-studio, https, android-volley

**Problem**

I'm attempting to make a simple POST JsonObjectRequest from a Huawei Watch and I keep getting `com.android.volley.TimeoutError`. I can successfully make other POST JsonObjectRequests from the watch to a different endpoint (not on my computer's localhost) and I can successfully make requests to the desired endpoint from a laptop.

**What I've Tried:**

- Most posts suggest that this error is due to a bad connection or an incorrect endpoint. **I tried increasing the timeout period** to see if my connection was just slow but this did not fix things. The endpoint is definitely correct as it works when I make the request from a laptop.
- I read on several posts that there are issues when connecting to unknown certificates. **I followed the quick fix outline here**: https://newfivefour.com/android-trust-all-ssl-certificates.html but this made no difference

**My Code**

```
mRequestQueue.add(volleyRequest());

...

private JsonObjectRequest volleyRequest(){
    JSONObject data = null;
    try{
        data = new JSONObject("{'some':'data','other':'data'}");
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(POST, mPath, data,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("Volley Response", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("Volley Error", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", mToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    return request;
}
```

Comment: What url are you using?  Is your server getting the requests?

Comment: The url is stored in `mPath`. It's the ip address of my computer, followed by the port number, followed by the path. Format is like "10.101.102.103:1234/data". No the server does not receive the request. So far the server doesn't do any processing, it just replies with the request that it is sent

Comment: I'd look into any and all firewalls/NATs/routers on the network you're on to make sure the request isn't being dropped.  I'm assuming both the device/simulator and laptop are on the same wifi network (or else it almost assuredly is).

Comment: Yes they are all on the same network. I'll look into the firewalls/NATs/routers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GabeSechan Everything seems ok with the firewalls, etc. I don't know a lot about that stuff, but other guys in the office have told me that it isn't an issue with the router or how it's set up. Any other thoughts?